# How do i make logical operation $or on array field in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a MongoDB collection, I have some data after an aggregation:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5411e00c0d42e2a3688b47d3"),
   "found" : [false, false, false, false],
}
```

How can I do the logical OR on array "found", to get `true` if any of elements is set to `true`, оf `false` if all elements are `false`?

I'm trying this, but it always returns `true`:

```
db.test.aggregate( {
       $project:
          {            
            found: { $or: "$found" }
          }
});

// "result" : [ 
//        {
//            "_id" : ObjectId("5411e00c0d42e2a3688b47d3"),
//            "found" : true
//        }
// ],
```

P.S. I am using MongoDB 2.6

Comment: In your case(using $or) `db.test.find( {"found" : true})` works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from version 2.6 you can use `$anyElementTrue`:

```
db.test.aggregate({
   $project: {            
     like: { $anyElementTrue: ["$found"] }
   }
});
```

See this:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/#exp._S_anyElementTrue

If you use earlier version then I'm afraid that you'll have to use either map/reduce or `$unwind -> $group` combination. Something like that:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "found"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "_id",
      like: { $or: "found" }
    }
  }
]);
```